# how to randomise the auth_token in jmeter

Tags: authentication, jmeter, bearer-token

in enter credentials[image1] request only access_token is generating but in login success[image2] request, authorization token is generating which is used in this and next requests as well. i don't know how to randomize it as in the same request extract the value and use, i am not able to do. does anyone help me and guide me how can i do it?
thanks
[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as child of the "Enter Credentials" request and configure it as follows:

   [image]

   it will extract the value of the `access_token` and store it into `token` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
2. Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) as a child of the "Login Success" request and configure it to send [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header with the value of `Bearer ${token}`

   [image]

This way "Login Success" request will send the token which is returned by the "Enter credentials" request. You will be able to refer it as `${token}` in any other place if needed.